# Express generating function g(x) using f(x)

Tags: discrete-mathematics, generating-functions

Let f(x) be generating function of the sequence {a<sub>n</sub>} and g(x) for the sequence {b<sub>n</sub>}. In following cases, express g(x) using f(x):

a) b<sub>3</sub> = 3; b<sub>n</sub> = a<sub>n</sub>; n≠3

b) b<sub>1</sub> = 1; b3 = 3; b<sub>n</sub> = 2a<sub>n</sub>, n≠1.3

c) b<sub>1</sub> = 1; b<sub>n</sub> = 2a<sub>n</sub> + 5, n≠1

I searched literally whole internet a I could not find any similar problem. Can you please help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Applying the definitions, you have
$$f(x)=a_0+a_1x+a_2x^2+a_3x^3+a_4x^4+\dotsb$$
and
$$g(x)=a_0+a_1x+a_2x^2+3x^3+a_4x^4+\dotsb$$
from which you obtain
$$
g(x)=f(x)+(3-a_3)x^3
$$
noting that
$$
f^{(3)}(0)=6{a_3}
$$
you can express $a_3$ in terms of $f$ and close the first question.

The others seem similar.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. It helped me a lot.